# how can i view an encrypted bin file without breaking it's encoding using ajax?

Tags: encoding, view, binary, hex, responsetext

the code

```
var xhr0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr0.open("get", 'page/file.bin', true);
xhr0.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        console.log("data:")
        console.log(xhr0.response)

        }
}
xhr0.send();
```

one of the response headers of the page

```
Content-Type: application/x-download;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

although i can't determine the exact encoding of the file cause it's encrypted .
i need to view the file the same as it's.. binary ( hexadecimal view ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using a [response type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

just like this

```
var xhr0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr0.open("get", 'page.bin', true);
xhr0.responseType =  "blob";
xhr0.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        console.log("data:")
        var blob1 = xhr0.response
        console.log(blob1)
            }
}
xhr0.send();
```

it will look like something like this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOrEf.png)